# C++ binary file - Writing ints - strange behaviour

Tags: c++, vector, binary-data

I have a simple vector of ints, and I want to write it into a binary file. For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<uint32_t> myVector{5, 10, 15, 20 };
    // write vector to bin file
    std::ofstream outfile("./binary_ints.data",  std::ios_base::binary|std::ios::trunc);
    std::copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outfile));
    outfile.close(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Then, if I inspect the file "binary_ints.data" in hex mode, I have this:

```
00000000: 050a 0f14 0a
```

Thats ok!.

However, If myVector has this data:

```
std::vector<uint32_t> myVector{3231748228};
```

Then, the hex stored is weird:

```
00000000: 840a
```

84 in Hex doesn't match with the Int 3231748228.
What's happening here?
Thanks.

Comment: `std::copy` doesn't transform one element into multiple new elements, nor does `std::ostreambuf_iterator`.

Comment: You could have done some experimentation to see what happens if the `int` value is > 255.

Comment: I'm curious where the extra newline is coming from (other than the one that is actually part of the vector data).  The program should not be writing one after the vector data.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, it is actually an interesting question. I did not see any newline in my tests during answer preparation. But as long as it is not a part of the question and I do not know how to reproduce it, I just did not do anything to resolve this "issue".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each value in your `std::vector<uint32_t>` is interpreted as `char` during your `std::copy ()` invocation. `3231748228` is represented in hex as `‭C0A09084`. `std::copy ()` takes `uint32_t` value, truncates it to single byte which is `0x84` on [Little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) processor. After writing byte `0x84` in file byte `0x0a` is added which corresponds to [new line character](http://www.asciitable.com/).

A possible solution is to use `ofstream::write()` instead of `std::copy ()`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<uint32_t> myVector{3231748228 };
    // write vector to bin file
    std::ofstream outfile("./binary_ints.data",  std::ios_base::binary|std::ios::trunc);

    outfile.write (
        (char*)(myVector.data ()), 
        myVector.size () * sizeof (decltype (myVector)::value_type));

    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of [`decltype ()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype). The same effect may be achivied by just writing `sizeof (uint32_t)`, but with `decltype ()` you may be sure that the code remains correct even if you change `myVector` value type.